# Query from Vava to MongoDB: find event in a specific date range

Tags: java, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query

I've got the following document in MongoDB:

```
{
"_id" : NumberLong(44),
"_class" : "la.test.app.server.model.Event",
"orgId" : NumberLong(2),
"typeCode" : 1,
"title" : "Test for notification",
"shortDescription" : "Test for notification",
"description" : "Test for notification",
"price" : "100",
"startDate" : ISODate("2015-02-08T16:30:07.000Z"),
"endDate" : ISODate("2015-02-09T16:00:07.000Z"),
"deleted" : false
}
```

I need to find this event among all others.

I'm trying to do such a simple thing with method:

```
public List<Event> getPendingEvents(Date start, Date end) {
   return mongoOperations.find(
        Query.query(Criteria
         .where("startDate").gte(start).lte(end)
         .and("typeCode").is("1")),

Event.class
);
```

That assembles and returns me query:

```
 {
"startDate" : { "$gte" : { "$date" : "2015-02-08T05:29:00.000Z"} ,
                "$lte" : { "$date" : "2015-02-08T05:31:00.000Z"}} ,
"typeCode":"1"
}
```

And this query finds just "Fields: null, Sort: null":

But a direct query to MongoDB:

```
db.events.find({
"startDate" : {"$gte" : ISODate("2015-02-08 16:30:07.000Z"),
               "$lt" : ISODate("2015-02-08 16:31:07.000Z")},
"typeCode" : 1})
```

Finds the required event.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried by formating the date by using  SimpleDateFormat...?

I had tried this long back...

```
//   Find documents by date of birth
  Date gtDate = null;
  try {
   gtDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse("1984-05-010T8:30:00.000Z");
  } catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  BasicDBObject dateQueryObj = new BasicDBObject("DateOfBirth",  new BasicDBObject("$lt", gtDate));
  cursor = documents.find(dateQueryObj);
  while(cursor.hasNext()) {
   System.out.println("\n Find documents by date of birth. \n");
      System.out.println(cursor.next());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem was solved by using BasicDBObject instead of a mongoOperations intreface.

Something like that:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query = new BasicDBObject("endDate", new BasicDBObject("$gte", start).append("$lte", end)).append("typeCode", 1);


    List<DBObject> result = collection.find(query).toArray();
```